# Spring Security: Case Insensitive Roles

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have setup Spring Security in my Spring MVC based web application. However due to some external system restriction, I want the user `roles` to be in lowercase.

But when testing locally using In Memory Users, the application allows access only when authenticated user has roles in UPPER_CASE, and gives 403 as soon as I change the roles to lowercase.

Is there an such restriction to have roles only in upper-case. I can't find any mention of it in docs ?

I also found out about attribute `lowercase-comparisons` for `filter-invocation-definition-source`.. is this for comparison of URL  or roles ?

Below is FilterSecurityInterceptor definition:

```
<bean id="fsi" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager" />
    <property name="objectDefinitionSource">
        <sec:filter-invocation-definition-source lowercase-comparisons="true">
            <sec:intercept-url pattern="/logout.jsp"            access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
            <sec:intercept-url pattern="/welcome.htm"           access="ROLE_executer,ROLE_viewer,ROLE_admin_user" />

            <!-- Write Access -->
            <sec:intercept-url pattern="/addNewRecord.htm"      access="ROLE_executer,ROLE_admin_user" />
            <sec:intercept-url pattern="/updateRecord.htm"      access="ROLE_executer,ROLE_admin_user" />
            <sec:intercept-url pattern="/deleteRecord.htm"      access="ROLE_executer,ROLE_admin_user" />
            <sec:intercept-url pattern="/uploadFile.htm"        access="ROLE_executer,ROLE_admin_user" />

            <!-- Read Access to All Other-->
            <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**"                    access="ROLE_executer,ROLE_viewer,ROLE_admin_user"/>                        
        </sec:filter-invocation-definition-source>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Roles don't have to be upper case. However, in a normal configuration, the `RoleVoter` looks for the prefix `ROLE_`, which is case sensitive. See [this FAQ](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/faq.html#faq-role-prefix).

You can either configure the role voter to have an empty prefix (or a lower case one, if that's what you want), or you can use expression-based access - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11549049/241990).

Alternatively, you can configure your `AuthenticationProvider` with a `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` which converts the roles from your external system to values which can be consumed by Spring Security's `RoleVoter` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636881/241990).

Comment: This is correct. Another thing worth pointing would be that these "Roles" are not roles in typical sense (roles/priviledge). These are merely GrantedAuthority represented as String. RoleVoter checks for existence of these granted authorities in the user's granted authorities.

Comment: They can be "typical roles" if you want them to. `GrantedAuthority` is just an internal interface and it's meaning depends on the voter. `RoleVoter` just compares the string representation with the access control attributes listed for the URL or secured method, which is a pretty typical interpretation of role-based access in an application.