# Is Spring security hasRole() and hasAnyRole casesensitive?

Tags: spring, spring-security, jstl

In the role table i am storing role name as "Admin", when i check

```html
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
    <c:out value='${message}'/> 
</sec:authorize>
```

its not printing the message even if i log in as Admin user.

**Is this expression case-sensitive**?

Comment: May be this post helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832510/spring-security-case-insensitive-roles

Answer (score 1):

If you need Spring jsp page authorization means follow the below steps,

Step 1: Need to activate web authorization in web security file

> **use-expressions="true" in http tag** in security xml file

ex: `<http .... use-expressions="true">`

then you configure pom.xml for download spring

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Step2. Then add the tag lib in your need jsp page

Ex:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

Step3: Then check the hasRole in jsp page

Ex:

```
<security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
    This text is only visible to a user
    <br/>
</security:authorize>
<security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    This text is only visible to an admin
    <br/>
</security:authorize>
```

In that place userRole is **case sensitive**

You can also provide the full page access based on role.. use follow sample code

```
<intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
```

This intercept allow role user in that page.

Based on in you question you should verify **web security file** must have `use-expression="true"`

If it is correct please make sure the role name.Because it is case sensitive